# How to use HTML Dropdown to get dababase values

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a Music database site for University using PHPMyAdmin. Right now, I need to make a process dropdown that allows the user to click on a drop down menu of artist names. When the user clicks on one of the given artists and clicks the send button, I want it to link to a page that contains the songs & details of the artist.. These are the [Tables](https://gyazo.com/5772952e1a0ee67cfcace0f73038038b). I need the SQL code in order to successfully link these together/ THANKS

Here is the [HTML Drop Down code](https://gyazo.com/95c9b8eb1378414c4af09b0612e4013b)

-- Please select artist name --

```
    <option>Drake</option>
    <option>ILOVEMAKONNEN</option>
    <option>Justin Bieber</option>
    <option>Kanye West</option>
    <option>Kendrick Lamar</option>
    <option>Post Malone</option>
    <option>ScHoolboy Q</option>
    <option>Taylor Swift</option>
    <option>Travis Scott</option>
    <option>Young Thug</option>
    </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
```

Answer (score 1):

From database fetch the artist name. Then use for() or foreach loop()
let say it is your arrtist array:
$arrArtist =('Drake','ILOVEMAKONNEN','Justin Bieber');

In html page

```
<select name="arrtistname">
<?php 
foreach($arrArtist as $artist)
{
<?php>
  <option value='<?php echo $artist?>'><?php echo $artist?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: I basically need the code so that when I select an artist, it shows me all the songs by them and the details of that song and the artist.. you understand. I need a SELECT query of some sort with a WHERE function as well.. Can I add you on anything to speak about this further. Maybe using Voip??

Comment: on-change of select box you can call the new page to show songs list.we can talk in hangout(gchat). just send email dipanwita.kundu@osscube.com